# OpenGL glTranslatef and glScalef

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I'm trying to implement a pan and pinch-to-zoom feature into an OpenGL application I have. I was able to implement the pan feature relatively easily with a simple `glTranslatef`, but using the `glScalef` function is presenting much more difficulty. I have three classes, one for the `GLSurfaceView`, one for the `GLTriangle`, and the third (below) for the `GLRenderer`, which is where the `glScalef` and `glTranslatef` are used.

`GLRenderer` Class:

```
public class GLRendererEx implements Renderer, OnTouchListener {

    private GLTriangleEx tri;
    float ratio;
    float x = 0, y = 0;
    float dx = 0, dy = 0;
    float sx = 0, sy = 0;
    float tx = 0, ty = 0;
    float xtwo = 0, ytwo = 0;
    float sxtwo = 0, sytwo = 0;
    float screenX, screenY;
    float xscale = 1, yscale = 1;
    float xscaletwo = 1;
    float xscaletotal = 1, yscaletotal = 1;
    int NONE = 0, DRAG = 1, ZOOM = 2;
    int mode = NONE;
    int width, height;
    boolean touched = true;
    Display getOrient = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    int orientation;

    public GLRendererEx() {
        tri = new GLTriangleEx();
        screenX = ourSurface.getWidth();
        screenY = ourSurface.getHeight();
        ourSurface.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig eglConfig) {
        gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DITHER);
        gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_FASTEST);
        gl.glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 1f);
        gl.glClearDepthf(1f);
        orientation = getOrient.getRotation();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        GLU.gluLookAt(gl, 0, 0, -5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0);

        //warning - x is backwards
        gl.glTranslatef(tx, ty, 0);
        gl.glScalef(xscaletotal, yscaletotal, 1);
        tri.draw(gl);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        ratio = ((float) width) / height;
        screenX = width;
        screenY = height;
        orientation = getOrient.getRotation();
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        gl.glFrustumf(-ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 1, 50);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            event.getActionIndex();
            sx = x = event.getX(0);
            sy = y = event.getY(0);
            mode = DRAG;
            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: {
            event.getActionIndex();
            sxtwo = xtwo = event.getX(1);
            sytwo = ytwo = event.getY(1);
            mode = ZOOM;
            touched = true;
            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: { 
            x = event.getX(0);
            y = event.getY(0);
            xtwo = event.getX(1);
            ytwo = event.getY(1);
            if (mode == ZOOM)
                midPoint(x, y, xtwo, ytwo);
            if (mode == DRAG) {
                dx = x - sx;
                dy = y - sy;
                dx *= -8;
                dy *= -8;
                if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) 
                    dx *= 2;
                dx /= screenX;
                dy /= screenY;
                tx += dx;
                ty += dy;
                sx = x;
                sy = y;
            }
            break;
        }       
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: {
            mode = DRAG;
            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
            mode = NONE;
            break;
        }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private float midPoint(float x, float y, float xtwo, float ytwo) {
        x -= xtwo;
        y -= ytwo;
        if (touched) {
            sxtwo = x;
            sytwo = y;
            xscaletwo = FloatMath.sqrt(sxtwo * sxtwo + sytwo * sytwo);
                            touched = false;
        }
                    xscale -= xscaletwo;
        xscale  = FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
        xscaletotal += xscale;
        yscaletotal = xscaletotal;
        return xscale;
    }

}
```

`x/y`'s are coordinates, `dx/dy` are the change in the coords, `sx/sy`'s are starting coords, `tx/ty` are the total changes in coords (for panning), `xscale/yscale`'s are the floats used to calculate the scale for zooming, `xscaletotal/yscaletotal` are total changes in zoom scale, none drag zoom and mode represent the mode.

As it stands, I can zoom in by pulling my fingers apart, but a pinch also zooms instead of zooming out. Also, the zoom is much too sensitive.

I don't really know how to solve this problem from here. Any help would be more than appreciated.

Comment: Despite the title, the question is really about correctly calculating scale of a pinch/zoom gesture, not about correct use of glScaleF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem your "midPoint" has some work to do.. Try doing something like this:

```
float scale = 1.0; //factor used in glScalef
float previousPinchScale; //needed to remember from previous methode call
private float midPoint(float x, float y, float xtwo, float ytwo) {
    float currentPinchScale = FloatMath.sqrt((x-xTwo)*(x-xTwo) + (y-yTwo)*(y-yTwo)); //current distance between both "touches"
    if (touched) { //gesture just began:
        previousPinchScale = currentPinchScale; //Save relative information about touch positions
        touched = false;
    }
    else { //gesture in progress:
        /*
         At this point we have 2 values of "PinchScale" for this and previous "midPoint" method call.
         The factor of relative change in this distance should be applied to current scene scale:
         currentPinchScale/previousPinchScale is the "relative change", for instance if the distance between the 2 touches would be 10% this factor would return 1.1
         Since we have to consider that scene might already be zoomed you need to take previous scale and multiply it with this change..
         */
        scale *= currentPinchScale/previousPinchScale; //scale used in glScalef
        previousPinchScale = currentPinchScale; //remember the new position of "midPoint" call
    }
    return scale;
}
```

Comment: I am completely surprised with the simplicity of this answer, although now I run into a separate problem I don't quite understand. The two touches to do a pinch zoom have to be so incredibly timed together that my test device (Galaxy S) usually can't detect a multi-touch, and my faster actual phone (Galaxy S3) can only detect one in every 100 pinches. How would I make the window of "touch-time" larger to make it easier to pinch?

Comment: I don't think this events have much to do window of touch time.. The best way to do such a thing is probably to get events when touches begin, move and end, or being able to get all touches and their positions at any given time and keep checking for changes. Even if you get any of those 2 you still need a good system to recognize the gesture itself... On the other hand, those gesture recognizers are already written for android, so why not use them?